# PHP exec not giving the same result as cmd

Tags: php, cmd, exec, sox

```
exec ("C:/Lame/sox \"C:/1/2.wav\" -t wav \"C:/1/2.rev\" reverse");
```

Using that code to use an audio post processing tool to reverse a sound file. There is an output but the file is about 1/5th the size it should be and I am unable to play it. Basically it makes a file but its not the one I would have gotten if I did this in the command prompt:

```
C:/Lame/sox "C:/1/2.wav" -t wav "C:/1/2.rev" reverse
```

With that, I get the result I want and I am able to play the rev file.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Do you execute them with the same user ?

Comment: Yes. Everything works. I can do other commands such as:

exec ("C:/Lame/sox \"C:/1/2.wav\" -t wav \"C:/1/2.rev\" pitch 1000");

And that would work. Only with this reverse is the issue but it works in the cmd.

Comment: Did you try with an array as output ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Yup. Doesnt change anything. I'm really confused why this doesnt work and have tried and looked at everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It was a permission problem.

All the other post processing command works because it writes in that folder. Reverse makes a temporary file in another folder which the current user didn't have write access in which why it made a small file since it tried to later read from a file that didn't exist.